# Two Angular Projects on single node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, server, angular5

I have two angular projects and I want to serve them on the same domain like for example if I do mywebsite.com/app1 get the first project and when I do mywebsite.com/app2 get the second project.

Comment: user different ports for each while serve project `ng serve --port 4200`

Comment: I don't want to server the project under different ports I want them on the same port but different routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need them to run on the same node server then just create controller routes for each to separate them. If you mean that you both need them to run on the same physical server then you can look into sub domains and have app1.mywebsite.com point to one running node server and app2.mywebsite.com point to another. This would allow them to be split between 2 node processes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make 2 folders inside dist for each app and serve the static files using express.static

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use('/app1', express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + './../dist/app1')));         
app.use('/app2', express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + './../dist/app2')));
```

Answer (score 0):

create two folder on your node app

- app1
- app2
  put the result of ng build of both project in those folders by editing your angular.json file and specify the `outDir`and the same for the scond app 'app2' :

  "outDir": "/path/to/your/node/app/app2"

  "outDir": "/path/to/your/node/app/app1"

then in your node app just tell the app which folder to serve from on the specific route :

```
app.use('/app1', express.static('app1'));
app.use('/app2', express.static('app2'));
app.use('/', express.static('index.html'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this code now, it is serving the correct app but in Angular it isn't finding the correct js files it's looking in the root directory like localhost:8080/main.js instead it must look at localhost:8080/app1/main.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use('/app1', express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + '/app/app1')));         
app.use('/app2', express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + '/app/app2')));
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server is litening on port 8080');
});
```